# data is not saved in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

```
  public void onSave(MenuItem item) {

        if (validate()) {

            Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
            value.put("Name", tvName.getText().toString());
            value.put("Number", Number.wildcardsViewToDb(tvNumber.getText().toString()));

            if(checkBoxRule.isChecked()) {
                value.put("Allow", 0);
            }
            else {
                value.put("Allow", 1);
            }


            /*ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            value.put(Number.NAME, tvName.getText().toString());
            value.put(Number.NUMBER, Number.wildcardsViewToDb(tvNumber.getText().toString()));

            if(checkBoxRule.isChecked()) {
                value.put(Number.ALLOW, 0);
            }
            else {
                value.put(Number.ALLOW, 1);
            }
            */

            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
            connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                    if (connected) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connected");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listener was cancelled");
                }
            });

            DatabaseReference block_numberRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Block_numbers");

            block_numberRef.push().setValue(value);

            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.block_number_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I followed all the posts about firebase real-time database.
However, it's not saving the value in the database.
it is saved on the local database but it didn't work in the firebase real-time database.
I wonder what's the problem is.
I'm making an android app by using java language and android studio.

Comment: `setValue(value)` returns a task which you can attach a [completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to. On success, toast that the block number was saved and on error, log/toast the error message. If the error you are getting is still unclear, edit it into this question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe enter the code like this move the hashmap below the Database Reference and no need for .push()

```
DatabaseReference block_numberRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Block_numbers");

Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
value.put("Name", tvName.getText().toString())
value.put("Number", Number.wildcardsViewToDb(tvNumber.getText().toString()));

block_numberRef.setValue(value);
```